# appending an <object> dynamically in IE doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I tried several methods, none seem to work:

**1** *(I tried this one with other elements and it doesn't work either)*:

```
$('#container').append('<object attribute="value"></object>');
```

**2** *(I found that this way worked with IE with most elements, but no luck here)* :

```
var newSwf = $('<object></object>').attr('attribute', 'value');
$('#container').append(newSwf); //appendTo doesn't work either
```

None of the above seems to have any effect on the DOM, like nothing is appending at all. I know IE works funny with the append function, but until now, I always managed to find a workaround. I have no clue with this one though. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

It seems it was my mistake, something else on my code was causing the problem in IE. I'm terribly sorry, I was hiting against a wall and I thought it was some sort of .append() issue, since IE always works funny with that.

The second method worked, as it does with other elements.

Comment: Did you see this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281246/how-can-i-dynamically-add-an-object-tag-with-javascript-in-ie

Comment: Which version are you talking about? It work on IE 8+. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/FGrAW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it works on [IE 8+](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/FGrAW/). But in case they are not, stick to native JavaScript for this

```
var newobject = document.createElement('object')
newobject.setAttribute('id','objectid');
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newobject);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/FGrAW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<object attribute="value"></object>';`