# Not able to render SVG image in Safari

Tags: html, safari, web, svg, rendering

As the title states, I have a svg image, but I am not able to render it in safari, and opera. But it works perfectly fine in Firefox. I found this post

[Doctype problem displaying SVG with Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117380/doctype-problem-displaying-svg-with-safari)

which has mentioned to change the content to xhtml. So, I added this on the top of my html page,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml">
```

But still it doesn't work.

I am embedding the svg image in my JS file like this

```
this.my_object.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="img/gauge.png" width="122" height="127"/><g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)"><circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/><polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/></g><text id="value" x="35" y="103" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text></svg>';
```

Can this be the reason? I am not calling it by conventional mechanism.

I am also pasting the svg code here,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g name="gauge" width="122px" height="127px">
        <image xlink:href="gauging.png" width="122" height="127"/>
    <circle id="led" cx="39" cy="76" r="5" style="fill: #999; stroke: none">
        <animateColor id="ledAnimation" attributeName="fill" attributeType="css" begin="0s" dur="1s"
        values="none;#f88;#f00;#f88;none;" repeatCount="0"/>
    </circle>
        <g id="needle" transform="rotate(0,62,62)">
            <circle cx="62" cy="62" r="4" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
            <rect transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" name="arrow"  x="58" y="38" width="8" height="24" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
            <polygon transform="rotate(-130,62,62)" points="58,39,66,39,62,30,58,39" style="fill: #c00; stroke: none"/>
        </g>
        <text id="value" x="51" y="98" focusable="false" editable="no" style="stroke:none; fill:#fff; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px"></text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Can anyone suggest the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future users: 
Found the reason to the problem. The accepted answer of this post [Safari embeded SVG doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372695/safari-embeded-svg-doctype?rq=1) explains the problem.

Solution to the problem :

Besides above, I configured my web.config file to add

```
<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" /></staticContent>
```

The server should send correct Content-Type header.

Problem solved! :)

Comment: To add an HTML object element via JS, look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281246/how-can-i-dynamically-add-an-object-tag-with-javascript-in-ie

Comment: I'm using Live Preview in VS Code, how do I configure this for production?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and discovered that because my polygons were self terminating, Safari 6.0.2 wouldn't render them. E.G.:

Doesn't work:

```
<polygon points='-3.172,-1.758 -6.208,-4.793 -8,-3 -8,-8 -3,-8 -4.792,-6.207 -1.757,-3.173'>
```

Works:

```
<polygon points='-3.172,-1.758 -6.208,-4.793 -8,-3 -8,-8 -3,-8 -4.792,-6.207 -1.757,-3.173'/>
```